# Set required attributes in TypeScript

Tags: interface, typescript, redux

What is a proper way in TypeScript to mark some attributes as **required**? Let's say we have certain object, that must contain **id** field, but can also have as many other fields as it wants:

```
interface SomeType {
    id: number;
}

let obj: SomeType = { name: "OBJ" };           // GOOD ERROR! We must have `id`
let obj: SomeType = { id: 123 };               // OK
let obj: SomeType = { id: 123, name: "OBJ" };  // BAD ERROR! I just want to add a name
```

I do know that you can make optional attributes with a question mark, like this:

```
interface SomeType {
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    engine?: string;
    mother?: string;
}
```

But I don't want each time modify this interface by adding and mixing unrelated things to it.

Another option is of course to create a *swarm of interfaces* each extending the  main one, but that sounds like a lot of lines of code:

```
interface SomeType {
    id: number;
}

interface FirstType extends SomeType {
    name: string;
}
```

At first I tried doing this:

```
interface SomeType extends any {
    id: number;
}
```

But TypeScript can't find name `any`. Maybe there is something like this with an exclamation point?

```
interface SomeType {
    id!: number;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am using this type of interface when creating [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) actions, which must have property `type` and any number of other additional attributes. There are really a lot of actions, so I was reluctant to use `any` as a type.

Comment: *“Set required attributes”* – Are you sure *that* is what you want to do? It sounds more to me like you want to define a type that has some (required) properties but allows any number of additional not-previously-defined properties. Please show usages of how you actually want to use this type so we get for what purpose you want to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an [indexer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) for that:

```
interface SomeType {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}

let obj1: SomeType = { name: "OBJ" };           // GOOD ERROR! We must have `id`
let obj2: SomeType = { id: 123 };               // OK
let obj3: SomeType = { id: 123, name: "OBJ" };  // OK
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20SomeType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20obj1%3A%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22OBJ%22%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20GOOD%20ERROR!%20We%20must%20have%20%60id%60%0Alet%20obj2%3A%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20123%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20OK%0Alet%20obj3%3A%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20123%2C%20name%3A%20%22OBJ%22%20%7D%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20OK)]

However, please note that even the following code (i.e. with a non-string property key) is valid with the indexer above:

```
let obj4: SomeType = { id: 123, 1: "OBJ" }; // also OK
```

which confuses people but it is as it is.

Comment: It shouldn't be confusing, since JavaScript objects have only stringy keys, and the numeric 1 is implicitly converted to stringy 1 in the object. With your `obj4`, if you run `Object.keys(obj4).map(key => typeof key)`, you'll see an array containing just `string`.

Answer (score 4):

> But I don't want each time modify this interface by adding and mixing unrelated things to it.

Don't add to or mix unrelated things in the same interface. Create separate interfaces and then combine them when necessary by using intersection types.

```
interface FirstType {
    id: number;
}

interface SecondType {
    name: string;
}

let myIntersectionObj: FirstType & SecondType = {
    id: 2,
    name: "some string"
};
```

That's useful in situations like this:

```
function myFirstFunction(obj: FirstType) { /* does something */ }
function mySecondFunction(obj: SecondType) { /* does something */ }

function myFunction(obj: FirstType & SecondType) {
    myFirstFunction(obj);
    mySecondFunction(obj);
}

myFunction(myIntersectionObj);
```

Using intersection types helps to make sure everything is typed in the application, which will help prevent mistakes. Indexed types should ideally only be used for key value objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try like below.

```
interface SomeType {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```